# Loop para alterar texto de uma célula (A) quando clicar em um botão (B) localizado na mesma linha que a célula (A) em uma tabela HTML

Tags: javascript, loop

Tenho uma tabela com datas na qual estou montando um botão que adiciona sete dias ao valor presente. Como são várias linhas, a intenção é que cada data tenha o seu próprio botão de adiamento, entretanto não consigo pegar a data atual da linha onde o botão responsável por alterá-la se encontra.

Em síntese, tentei usar `filterItem[i]` para pegar a data de cada linha, mas não funciona. No código abaixo, deixei apenas a terceira linha seleciona (o que me dá um indicativo de que o laço de repetição não está funcionando):

Onde estou errando?

```js
var filterItem = document.getElementById('table').querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)')
var adiarEntrega = document.querySelectorAll('.adiar')

for (var i = 0; i < filterItem.length; i++) {
    var dataAtual = filterItem[i].innerHTML;
    var botao = adiarEntrega[i];
    botao.addEventListener('click', function() {
          
    var datainicial = filterItem[2].innerHTML;
    var dias = parseInt(7);
    var partes = datainicial.split("/");
    var ano = partes[2];
    var mes = partes[1]-1;
    var dia = partes[0];

    datainicial = new Date(ano,mes,dia);
    datafinal = new Date(datainicial);
    datafinal.setDate(datafinal.getDate() + dias);

    var dd = ("0" + datafinal.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var mm = ("0" + (datafinal.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
    var y = datafinal.getFullYear();

    var dataformatada = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
    filterItem[2].innerHTML = dataformatada
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
  <th>Coluna 1</th>
  <th>Coluna 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="adiar">Avançar 7 dias --> </td>
    <td>12/03/2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="adiar">Avançar 7 dias --> </td>
    <td>15/06/1962</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="adiar">Avançar 7 dias --> </td>
    <td>23/11/2009</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>sei que essa reposta poderia ser um comentário, mas eu quis tentar elaborar uma explicação clara do assunto abordado...</sub>

O seu caso é um grave problema de escopo por causa do `var`, ele não mantém o escopo da variável `i` dentro do `for`, ou seja, o valor de `i` fica acessível em todo o escopo do script, o que gera em resultados inesperados. No final do loop, o `i` vale `3` e isso gera o erro abaixo se tentarmo usar `var datainicial = filterItem[i].innerHTML;` dentro da função do `eventListener`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: filterItem[i] is undefined
```

E isso é fato, se você fizer um `console.log(i)` dentro do *listener*, ele vai sempre mostrar `3`, pois o valor de `i` foi atualizado por causa do `i++`, então vai gerar o código `filterItem[3].innerHTML` e `filterItem[3]` é `undefined`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < filterItem.length; i++) {
  var dataAtual = filterItem[i].innerHTML;
  var botao = adiarEntrega[i];
  botao.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(i) // mostra sempre "3"

    // var datainicial = filterItem[i].innerHTML; <- vai lançar um erro
    var datainicial = filterItem[2].innerHTML;
    var dias = parseInt(7);
    var partes = datainicial.split('/');
    var ano = partes[2];
    var mes = partes[1] - 1;
    var dia = partes[0];

    datainicial = new Date(ano, mes, dia);
    datafinal = new Date(datainicial);
    datafinal.setDate(datafinal.getDate() + dias);

    var dd = ('0' + datafinal.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var mm = ('0' + (datafinal.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var y = datafinal.getFullYear();

    var dataformatada = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
    filterItem[2].innerHTML = dataformatada;
  });
}
```

Para resolver isso, usamos a *keyword* `let` para garantir que o escopo não vai ser extrapolado, que o valor de `i` para cada `filterItem[i].innerHTML` seja o valor correspondente no loop `for`.

Veja abaixo o código e ainda coloquei um `console.log` para imprimir o valor do `i`:

```js
var filterItem = document.getElementById('table').querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)')
var adiarEntrega = document.querySelectorAll('.adiar')

//   ↓↓↓ não use "var"
for (let i = 0; i < filterItem.length; i++) {
  var dataAtual = filterItem[i].innerHTML;
  var botao = adiarEntrega[i];
  botao.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(i); // mostra o valor de acordo com o loop
    //                          ↓↓↓ podemos usar o "i" sem problemas agora
    var datainicial = filterItem[i].innerHTML;
    var dias = parseInt(7);
    var partes = datainicial.split('/');
    var ano = partes[2];
    var mes = partes[1] - 1;
    var dia = partes[0];

    datainicial = new Date(ano, mes, dia);
    datafinal = new Date(datainicial);
    datafinal.setDate(datafinal.getDate() + dias);

    var dd = ('0' + datafinal.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var mm = ('0' + (datafinal.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var y = datafinal.getFullYear();

    var dataformatada = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
    filterItem[i].innerHTML = dataformatada;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
  <th>Coluna 1</th>
  <th>Coluna 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="adiar">Avançar 7 dias --> </td>
    <td>12/03/2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="adiar">Avançar 7 dias --> </td>
    <td>15/06/1962</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="adiar">Avançar 7 dias --> </td>
    <td>23/11/2009</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Para saber mais sobre [`var`, `let` e escopo no JavaScript](https://hcode.com.br/blog/entenda-a-diferenca-entre-var-let-e-const-no-javascript).

Comment: Que massa, Iglan! Então era só usar `let` ao invés de `var`? Muito obrigado pelo retorno e pela clara explicação, meu caro!

Comment: Exato! Nao use mais `var`,  apenas `let` e `const` para declarar variaveis.

Comment: Valeu pela dica! =]